# Is Mindcrash the "end" of the game?

Tags: hypnospace-outlaw

I've been playing Hypnospace Outlaw and I just got to a plot element which, for the sake of not spoiling the game for others, I will just call Mindcrash.

Is this the end of the game? Have I reached endgame? If so I'm somewhat underwhelmed

Comment: Feel free to use the spoilers markdown `>!` to help explain your question better.